# React Uncaught TypeError: transcript.Transcription.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-hooks, aws-amplify

I'm writing a React script where I have to map through a string inside a map function.

```
const set = new Set(["I", "deck", " Yes."]);
      const arr =  value.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
      var v = 0   
return <RightWrapper>
        <Header>
          <Button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete Transcription</Button>
          <Button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</Button>
        </Header>
        
        {
    arr.map(transcript => (
      
      transcript.Transcription.map(word => (
        <p key={transcript.id}
       
        
        style={{
          color: set.has(word) ? 'red' : 'black'
        }}
        >{transcript.createdAt + "  " + transcript.Transcription + " "} </p>


      ))
    )

     
      )
  }
          </RightWrapper>;
```

Objective - to check if any word inside the string transcript.Transcription is in the set. If yes then highlight that word.

transcript.Transcription is a sentence(string)

Comment: The error suggests that `transcript.Transcription` is not an array.  So what is it?  Why do you expect it to be an array?

Comment: `where I have to map through a string` you can't do this, you map through an array. Instead look up `string.includes()`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `set.has(word)` instead of `set.has(transcript.Transcription)`

Comment: @David transcript.Transcription is a string (sentence)

Comment: @AnindyaDey yes apologies , I've edited it now

Comment: @user8112228: Well, `.map()` is a function on arrays.  What is the goal of calling it on a string?

Comment: @David I didn't know that .map() doesn't work with strings. Basically I just want to highlight any substring(word) in transcribe.Transcription that is in the set.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably other ways of doing it, but this is what I could come up with the information you have provided:

1. [OPTIONAL] Use arrays if possible (because there is a built-in [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function that checks if at least one object in the array satisfies a given condition)
2. I am converting the reference words (I call them "keywords" in the below example) into a Regular Expression, and I invoke the [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method on these
3. For the input words that return `true` you could use your styling logic and apply the necessary styles.

```js
// const keywords = ["I", "Programmer"]
const keywords = new Set(["I", "Programmer"])
const inputWords = ["I am a Programmer", "He is a Programmer", "She was a coder", "Yes, I love JS"]

function hasMatch(word, keywords) {
  for (let kw of keywords) {
    let regex = new RegExp(kw)
    if (regex.test(word)) return true
  }
  return false
}

inputWords.forEach(word => console.log(`${word} --> ${hasMatch(word, keywords)}`))

if (inputWords.some(word => hasMatch(word, keywords))) {
  console.log('Found at least one match!')
}
```

**NOTE**: The regex is case-sensitive. [You could make it insensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) by adding an extra parameter `i` to its constructor